# Heroku hosted Spring Boot application not always getting POST request from Axios

Tags: reactjs, spring, spring-boot, heroku, axios

First to say that both frontend and backend work properly when run locally.

I have hosted a Spring Boot backend which uses Spring Security and the "/users" url which is supposed to get a POST request and insert a new user in the Mongo database doesn't get the request most of the time. I say most of the time because the request sometimes goes trough.
All other requests to all urls work perfectly normal except to that url.

Sending a POST request to that url with Postman works without any problems.
Also I have tried sending a request from my frontend running locally and it stil doesn't go trough.

My backend is hosted here: https://secret-ridge-01197.herokuapp.com/

This is my controller for handling the Post request:

```
@PostMapping("/users")
public User saveUser(@RequestBody User newUser){
    String encryptedPassword = encodePasswordToBcrypt(newUser.getPassword());
    newUser.setPassword(encryptedPassword);
    return userRepository.save(newUser);

}
```

These are security and cors configurations:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().cors().and().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/login","/users").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilterBefore(new LoginFilter("/login", 
authenticationManager()),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
            .addFilterBefore(new AuthenticationFilter(),
                    UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class);
    http.requiresChannel().requestMatchers(r -> r.getHeader("X-Forwarded-Proto") != null)
            .requiresSecure();
}

@Bean
CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
    UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
    CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
    config.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
    config.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
    config.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
    config.setAllowCredentials(true);
    config.applyPermitDefaultValues();

    source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", config);
    return source;
}
```

This is the axios call from React where url is https://secret-ridge-01197.herokuapp.com :

```
export const addUser = user => async dispatch => {
const res = await axios.post(`${url}/users`, user);

dispatch({
 type: ADD_USER,
 payload: res.data
 });
};
```

I should be able to insert the user to the database by sending that POST request but I have noticed that it is received as a OPTION request in the heroku application logs. 
When I insert it trough Postman and try to login via site, it works also.

[This is what I get in the Network panel when I send the request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vseJW.jpg)

Frontend hosted on Heroku: https://dailycalories.herokuapp.com

Note that both frontend and backend are hosted on Heroku separately.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The `OPTION` is the pre-flight request from the browser.  Have you tried using Spring Boots `@CrossOrigin` annotation instead of trying to roll your own?

Comment: @JakeLuby thank you for answering. Yes I have, still the same issue.